# CSS class selector is not working on form.collection_select Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, css

I am trying apply some styling to `form.collection_select` helper class in Rails 5. But Unfortunately its not getting applied.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong:

1)

```
<%= form.collection_select(:manager_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, :include_blank => "Select None", :class => "input-with-icon") %>
```

2)

```
<%= form.collection_select(:manager_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, :include_blank => "Select None", {:class => "input-with-icon" }) %>
```

Returns :

```
<select name="user[manager_id]" id="user_manager_id">
<option value="">Select None</option>
<option value="15601867">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `collection_select` is built like this ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)):

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

So you need to pass an hash for the select options and an other hash for the html options:

```rb
<%= form.collection_select(:manager_id, User.all, :id, :full_name, { include_blank: "Select None" }, { class: "input-with-icon" }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked.  I was missing {} for options